# Cannot disable UITapGesture in childView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ContainerView with two child Views `A` and `B`, 
`A is a TableViewController` and `B is a CollectionViewController`. 
In B, when I `press on a collectionViewCell` a **detailView is loaded**. detailView is a simple `UIViewController` with an `UIImageView`. 
I've set up a **UISwipeGesture on B** to show the `tableViewController A` on the left side. 
**What i need**
Now I don't want to show the tableViewController when I'm on detailView,
so I need to disable the UISwipegesture but only when I'm in detailView

**What i done**
I've set up UIGestureDelegate but delegate methods aren't getting called.
With userInteractionEnambled=NO nothing change, except if I insert in detailView the following line myContainerViewController.view.userInteractionEnambled=NO;

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some of your code and reformat your question a bit?

Comment: Setting up a delegate for the gesture recognizer is the appropriate way to handle this.  You would need to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` in your delegate.

Comment: I've tried that but i couldn't manage to get that method called. I've put myGetsure.delegate=self and <UIGestureDelegate> but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference of the swipe gesture in a property and disabile it when you show the detail controller like this:

```
self.swipeGesture.enabled = NO;
```

Then you can re-enabled it in the viewWillAppear method of the main view controller, or when you dismiss the detail view.

Comment: Ok, can you please explain a little bit more please? I've already tried to put in myCollectionViewController prepareForSegue myGesture.enabled=NO but nothing change

Comment: Try removing also the delegate of the gesture recognizer. The gesture should not fire if you disable it, but if it is firing try checking if the property is initialized correctly.

Comment: Man you're right! If I put  NSLog(@"%@", self.tapGestureRecognizer.enabled ); I obtain null value in console, so what should I do? II still can't figure what to do

Comment: Is your gesture initialized via code or via Interface Builder?

Comment: I've finally solve this, It turns out that this wasn't a UIGesture but the slide effect was implemented in scrollview method.